# Pandas: Selecting rows by condition on column and index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, select

Assume we have the following dataframe:

```
d = {'col1': ['a1', 'b1', 'c1', 'a1'], 'col2': ['a2', 'b2', 'b2', 'c2'], 'year':[2011, 2011, 2012, 2012], 'rank':[1, 2, 1, 2]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d).set_index(['year', 'rank']).sort_index()

          col1 col2
year rank          
2011 1      a1   a2
     2      b1   b2
2012 1      c1   b2
     2      a1   c2
```

How can I select all columns where `col1 != 'a1'` or `year != 2011`?

If `year` wouldn't be an index, I could do this by

```
df[(df.col1 != 'a1') | (df.year != 2011)]
```

However, as year is an index, `df.year` would throw an AttributeError.

How can I formulate the condition for the index? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you absolutely need to use those columns as the index?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can access the index by the method `df.index.get_level_values`, e.g. you can gain the searched result by

```
In [29]: df[(df.col1 != 'a1') | (df.index.get_level_values('year') != 2011)]
Out[29]:
          col1 col2
year rank
2011 2      b1   b2
2012 1      c1   b2
     2      a1   c2
```

**Some Sidenote:**

The comparison `df.index.get_level_values('year') != 2011` will be an numpy array, therefore we need to get the values from the `pd.Series` for comparing with `df.col1 != 'a1'` (in some older pandas versions you may have used to acess the values with `.values` or similar, because comparing of an series with index with some array was not possible. Howewer, at least with 0.24 and above this is not necessary anymore).

Comment: Oh yes, that's true. That behaviour seem to have changed some while ago, when it didn't worked to compare some indexed series with an array, I'll adjust that. Thanks for pointing out!

Answer (score 2):

You can use the method `query()` that treats both the index and columns of the frame as a column:

```
df.query("col1 != 'a1' | year != 2011")
```

Output:

```
          col1 col2
year rank          
2011 2      b1   b2
2012 1      c1   b2
     2      a1   c2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access the index through `loc` and `iloc` operators.

```
df[df['col1'] != 'a1'].loc[2011]
```

To access both the year and rank index together, `df.loc[2011,1]`, which will output `a1 and a2`

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```py
df1 = df[df.index.get_level_values('year').isin([2011])]
df2 = df[df.col1 == 'a1']
result = pd.concat([df1,df2]).drop_duplicates()
```

---

**Output**

```
        col1    col2
year    rank        
2011    1   a1  a2
        2   b1  b2
2012    2   a1  c2
```